# Make turtle overtake another turtle

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to work on the NetLogo's TrafficBasic model.
I have this road:

```
to setup-road ;; patch procedure
  if (pycor > 0) and (pycor < 3) [ set pcolor red] ;1st lane
  if (pycor > -3) and (pycor < 0) [ set pcolor blue] ;2nd lane
end
```

*and this turtles(cars):*

```
to setup-cars
  if number-of-cars > world-width [
    stop
  ]
  set-default-shape turtles "car"
  create-turtles number-of-cars [
    setxy 2 2
    set heading 90
    set speed 0.1 + random-float 0.9
    set speed-limit 0.5
    set speed-min 0
  ]
end
```

*to go procedure:*

```
to go
  ask turtles [
    let car-ahead one-of turtles-on patch-ahead 1
    ifelse car-ahead != nobody[
        slow-down-car car-ahead 
        ]

         [
           speed-up-car
         ] 
    if speed < speed-min [ set speed speed-min ]
    if speed > speed-limit [ set speed speed-limit ]
    fd speed
  ]
  tick
end
```

I'm trying to get turtles overtake the turtle ahead but I can't figure out how can I do that.

**What I have tried:** to set heading to a slightly upper angle like 91 then to return turtle to it's main lane but it doesn't work as expected.

```
ifelse car-ahead != nobody[ ;overtake
          set heading 95
          set speed-limit 1
        ]

        [                  ;return to your lane and slow down
          set heading 90
          set speed-limit 0.5
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **elif**

```
ifelse car-ahead != nobody[ ;overtake
          set heading 95
          set speed-limit 1
        ]

        [                  ;return to your lane and slow down
          set heading 90
          set speed-limit 0.5
        ]
```